# How do I specify optional arguments in a constraint in F#?

Tags: f#

Let's say I have a method that takes some optional parameters, is there a way to use that method through a generic constraint?

I would like to do something like this:

```
type SomeClass() =
    member
        this.SomeMethod(?a:int, ?b:int) = 
            match a,b with
            | Some x, Some y -> x + y
            | _, _ -> 0
    member 
        this.SomeMethod (a:int,b:int) = a + b

// This doesn't work
let inline someMethod (a: ^T when ^T : (member SomeMethod: (?x:int)*(?y:int)->int)) = 
    (^T : (member SomeMethod: ?int*?int->int) (a,2,3))

let inline someMethod (a: ^T when ^T : (member SomeMethod2: int*int->int)) = 
    (^T : (member SomeMethod2: int*int->int) (a,2,3))
```

Is it possible in F#?

Answer (score 3):

Of course I figured out the answer right after, but here it is for everyone else:

```
type SomeClass() =
    member
        this.SomeMethod(?a:int, ?b:int) = 
            match a,b with
            | Some x, Some y -> x + y
            | _, _ -> 0
    member 
        this.SomeMethod (a:int,b:int) = a + b

let inline someMethod (a: ^T when ^T : (member SomeMethod: int option*int option->int)) = 
    (^T : (member SomeMethod: int option*int option->int) (a,Some 2,Some 3))

let inline someMethod2 (a: ^T when ^T : (member SomeMethod2: int*int->int)) = 
    (^T : (member SomeMethod2: int*int->int) (a,2,3))

let a = new SomeClass()
someMethod a
```

Comment: Strictly speaking optional arguments (not arguments of Option type) may not be used in method constraints per language specification (page 142): http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf

Comment: @Petr, that was exactly what I was struggilng with. Didn't know I had to specify the full "denormalized" version of the method and pass in option values to the optional arguments.